# Record type with automatic inference (e.g. `uknown`) from object literal

Tags: typescript

In typescript, I can either leave an object literal untyped so that type is automatically inferred, or I can specify a type (e.g. `Record`) so the type is enforced on the literal. -- (1)

I'd like to enforce `Record<unknown, A>` so that properties can be inferred from the literal (as an union type like `"prop1" | "prop2" | "prop3"`) and values are type-checked against `A`.

I.e. I want to ask typescript to do half of what it does in each case in (1).

Is this possible? `Record<unknown, A>` complains instead of inferring type for unknown

```
TS2344: Type 'unknown' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.   Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
```

See a minimal reproduction [at this typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7RgXhgbwFAxgQxgC4YBGAGlxgCMSAiAdwAt8oBTANzaTuwF9s2UJFiIUUAB7EYUAJ4AHNiDjxkqDGACuAG20BCANzYA9MZgBzBFwgEwBTVBCgAtvO1t2MCJvPm20BHBsMWgJADp8IyFwVAg2YQATaQAleJAkBIAeaCQEMHNyGC1nam4APnQsKkISCipTCyt-AhkFNhhuJHTC-Bs2CUVgdgTC5jY7TTAXZ3Hh+rNqaUYWdi4efkFhWLSwBKkSOUVlLx2kjR19EzMAOQB5GABBAFUAFVuAYVuAWQAFABkAKIvAEwADKTwA4hCAaCXgBJW7XbBxRLhSKCBoARRITBADBgwHwdgY7RYXBoICgTFaigJTHiAGs8uZ4OkYBx8NpNP4ert7I4XG4PO1vL5-FBApBWUgYAy2LIbPgHCBnKwEITdLIYHk4J02Ek4F1nDBtAh2EhOQB+GBXGDHUCaFDtEkEokwBLxbT4JDtQ7tOWyP2VOj4OgwAA+MDo1DD1AcMhW2psPsUEolXEKZtdYGMEFxOiSACtNKhStqwLqkD6DUaE+1TebOba4R0BvFhnXWbo8cyZCAYAx0gyaPGswkQP4wAByKDREQJ5BJEipUAZTKTBlgPFgQrFUpICoYHB4GpkSh4BqWawtIOdboEPptob6qiLejMVicbi8ARAA)

Comment: This would require [partial type inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), which Typescript doesn't have yet. The only solution here I can think of is letting TS infer the type and then verifying the type of the record values

Comment: @Joonas thanks. I'd figured that maybe it's not possible and was planning to open an issue, but thanks to you we found the open issue. I think link to the issue + an example of your suggestion is suitable as an answer. You may post it and I'll accept it. Additionally, do you think the inference + enforcement pattern you're suggesting could be described as a function (to make it re-usable)?

Comment: Posted with small example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would require [partial type inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), which Typescript doesn't have yet.

One solution here would be to let TS infer the type and then verify the type of the record values, ie. something like

```
const obj = {
  prop1: 'foo',
  prop2: 42,
  prop3: true
}

function fun<Keys extends string>(input: Record<Keys, string | number>) {}

fun(obj) // error: boolean not an accepted value
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. I'll try to generify the function for the second argument (`string | number`) so that it's a general-purpose utility function.